# What happens when a Ghost's haunted location is destroyed or it is otherwise unable to finish its business?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, spirits

There was an old ghost captain of a Spelljammer, who crashed his jammer and was bound to haunt it until he could resolve his guilt over the death of his crew due to his incompetence.

But then the players happened, and they set the shipwreck on fire, stole the dimensional anchor holding the thing in place and then caused the entire piece of land the spelljammer crashed on to fall into the void. You know, player things.

But they never did deal with the ghostly captain, who is now without a location to haunt. The monster manual just mentions that "a Ghost is bound to haunt a location", but it doesn't have anything on what happens when that location is destroyed.

Is there other lore on Ghosts that explains what happens when a Ghost loses the thing that keeps them around as a Ghost? Does it let them become free, turn them into something else, or do they normally just stop existing?

I'd like to keep the Ghost around a bit longer (and will make something up if needed) but am also curious if there is a "usual" D&D answer to this situation.

Comment: I'm a little confused that you say the ghost has no location to haunt.  Wouldn't it be stuck riding its ship into the void?

Comment: @DarthPseudonym that might also be an answer. I assumed it wouldn't do that, but maybe it should have.

Comment: Does 'void' in this context mean 'empty space' or some kinda ultimate nonexistence so that entering it is utter destruction?  If the ship still *exists* but is just somewhere the ghost wouldn't want to be, I think it's stuck with it.  If going into the void is like going into a *sphere of annihilation* then I think it's valid that the ship is just gone.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym the whole area was essentially disintegrated, there's nothing left but empty space.

Answer (score 5):

There is no requirement that a ghost's unfinished business has a possibility of resolution; if a a ghost's business can't be resolved for one reason or another, then logically, it can't be gotten rid of by finishing that business. It's actually not that uncommon for adventures that feature ghosts to mention that the ghost is trapped in its unlife because there is no possibility of completing its unfinished business.

Heck, forget D&D, in real life ghost lore, a ghost is often said to be "waiting for her lover's return" or "watching for a ship that will never arrive" or some such thing. That's their "unfinished business", and it *can't* be finished because the person is dead or the ship sank.

There's no rules for what to do when a haunted place or object (what we might call the ghost's "anchor") is destroyed.  Maybe destroying the anchor also destroys the ghost or forcibly makes it pass on into the afterlife -- it's not that unusual for modern ghost stories to end with a haunted object being burned to cut the ghost's tie to the mortal world. But maybe the ghost instead transfers its haunting to the person who destroyed the anchor, or maybe some debris survives and it starts haunting that (like say shifting from the ship to the ship's wheel or bell). It's the narrative the DM wants to tell, not any specific rule.

Comment: This suggests the ghost remains behind, except it's no longer bound to any location, so it can wander freely?

Comment: @Erik pretty sure it suggest that the ghost can be destroyed in this way. "The surest way to rid an area of a ghost is to resolve its unfinished business" means "the surest way to end a ghost's existence is to resolve its unfinished business."

Comment: @Erik No... Does this update clarify it?  My intent was to say that destroying the "anchor" object *might* free the ghost to pass on to the afterlife as it's meant to, much like finishing its business, but it could just mean the ghost becomes stuck to a new anchor.

Comment: Adding that changing the anchor to be the players (because they destroyed his ship) would be a *wonderful* way to keep the ghost in the game in a very real way that also makes the world feel more reactive and "alive" to the players.  They did a thing, now they have a ghost captain haunting them wherever they go.  That's a fantastic plot hook!